# Getting Error Illegal string offset After upgrade of PHP

Tags: php, mybb

Warning [2] Illegal string offset 'title' - Line: 66

```
if(!isset($params['title'])) {
    $params['title'] = "Hidden Content";
  }
```

and
Warning [2] Illegal string offset 'title' - Line: 3

```
   $return = $content;

  }

  eval("\$return = \"".$templates->get("lock_wrapper")."\";");

    return $return;

}
```

Any Solution is appreciated

Comment: Can you give us an exampleof what `$templates->get("lock_wrapper")` returns ? Your `eval` sound quite weird.

Comment: https://findjobsarkari.in/showthread.php?tid=1&pid=1#pid1

You can see the error and return on the above link.

Comment: Can you post the file `inc/plugins/lock/core/shortcode.php`, if it's not too long? We would need an extra bit of context in order to help you.

Comment: its too long but here is the full code https://pastebin.com/rBZEmJc8

Comment: @MathieuBour any solution mate?

Comment: Which file is this code in?